# Push object to s3 via aws ruby api v2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to upload a file to amazon s3 but I'm getting the following error:

```
Aws::S3::Errors::PermanentRedirect: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
```

Here is how I'm doing it:

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new('xxxx', 'xxx'),
  region: 'us-west-2'
)

obj = s3.bucket('dev.media.xxx.com.br').object('key')
obj.upload_file('/Users/andrefurquin/Desktop/teste.pdf', acl:'public-read')
obj.public_url
```

I'm sure I'm using the right region, credentials etc..

What can I do ?

Comment: That sound right to me. Are you sure of the name of your bucket and the object? The object should have the absolute path.

Comment: What is this is this the actual endpoint of bucket you are using dev.media.xxx.com.br?

Comment: Bah... I found out my region was east-1...

Comment: Follow this link it might help you https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=710051.

Comment: I have solved the problem. I was passing the wrong region..

Comment: Thank you.. I have wasted a lot of time because of that :/